# Help needed in understanding the lab observation regarding a diode

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, diodes, measurement, multimeter

I was trying to understand the connections in a power supply board.

It was found that anode of below diode is connected to GND and -ve terminal of bulk capacitor.
Cathode of diode is connected to +ve terminal of bulk capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGK6Gg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One strange measurement result was found when I measured the resistance wrt GND for the 2 cases shown above. The diode orientation is not reflecting correctly while measuring the resistance wrt GND.

**Has it got anything with the way the multimeter  measures resistance ( by injecting a voltage thereby charging the bulk caps?)**

I could find some voltage of 0.2V across diode after the above resistance measurement.

Comment: What results did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Many analog multimeters actually present a positive voltage out of the black/negative lead and vise versa.

Most digital multimeters operate the obvious way with a positive voltage from the red lead.

That would explain the results you get.

Do you have the manual of the meter? What meter is it?